# Haskell currying explanation needed

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm trying to understand the concept of currying and went to the [Haskell documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying). However, it says that

> f is the curried form of g

Yet f takes two arguments and g only one. Since currying is converting a function which takes multiple arguments to a function which takes one argument and returns another function, shouldn't 'g' be the curried function?

From the haskell documentation

> Currying is the process of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments into a function that takes just a single argument and returns another function if any arguments are still needed.

```
f :: a -> b -> c
is the curried form of
g :: (a, b) -> c
```

So this does seem contradictory to me and I also don't see any of these 2 functions return a function either.

Comment: A function that takes one k-tuple argument is sometimes said to take k arguments. This is normal terminology in mathematics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Yet `f` takes two arguments and `g` only one.

No, in fact *both* functions take *one* parameter. In fact in Haskell *all* functions take *exactly* one parameter.

If you write a signature like:

```
f :: a ->  b -> c
```

then this is a less verbose form of:

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
```

How does that work? `f` is a function that takes one parameter, and then returns another *function* that again takes a parameter.

So take for example a function `add :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

If we write `add 5 2`, we thus calculate `5 + 2`. It looks like it takes two parameters, but in fact we have written `(add 5) 2`. We thus call the `add` function with `5` as parameter. This returns a function (let us call this function `add5 :: Int -> Int`). So this `add5` function adds `5` to a number. So if we then call `add5 2`, then we obtain `7`, since `add5` returns `5` added to the parameter.

We can however construct a function (like `g`) that takes one parameter that is a 2-tuple, so we can use another type to pass two values as *one* parameter. In fact you can see `g(5, 2)` is actually `g (5, 2)`: you *call* the function with *one* parameter, a 2-tuple `(5, 2)`.

So the currying aims to transform such `g` function that takes *one* parameter (a 2-tuple) into a function `f` that takes again *one* parameter, and this will then construct a function that will take the second element of the original 2-tuple.

Answer (score 6):

The type `a -> b -> c` is actually `a -> (b -> c)`.

So `f` doesn't take two arguments, of type `a` and a `b` and return `c`, it takes one argument of type `a`, and returns `b -> c`, a function from `b` to `c`.